# Ports Needed Open for Windows VPN

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn

I just installed a Routing and Remote Access VPN service on Windows Server 2008, though I'm not totally sure what ports I need open for that, or what type of VPN I'm using. L2TP, PPTP?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- PPTP uses port TCP/1723 and the GRE(47) protocol.
- L2TP is usually transported over IPSEC which uses protocol AH(51), ESP(50), and UDP/500.

See:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233256
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263925
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241251
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754634(WS.10).aspx

Comment: I also have the machine set up to use Active Directory... Will authentication happen through AD, or do I need to set something else up for that?

Comment: The VPN tunnel will allow remote computers to think that they are on the same LAN or switch as the server. So you have full freedom about deciding how remote machines/users authenticate after they've negotiated and established the VPN tunnel.